# Let $G$ be a group of order $36$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with order 4. Then which is/are true?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $36$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with order 4. Then

(1) $H\subset Z(G)$

(2) $H=Z(G)$

(3) $H$ is normal in $Z(G)$

(4) $H$ is abelian group

Can I tell $H$ abelian, because $o(H)=4$? (Any group of order 4 is abelian).
 Once  $H$ abelian then $H=Z(H)\neq Z(G)$.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly (2) is false. A hint: What happens if $G$ is abelian?

You are correct with (4) though. Any group of order 4 is abelian, so that's good. However, it does not follow that $Z(H) \neq Z(G)$. There are certainly subgroups $H$ of non-abelian groups for which $Z(H) = Z(G)$, even though $H \neq G$.