# For any group $G$ of order $36$ and any subgroup $H$ of $G$ order $4$ which is correct

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $36$ and H be any subgroup of $G$ order $4$ then

(a) $H$ $\subset$ $Z(G)$

(b) $H$ $=$ $Z(G)$

(c) $H$ is normal $G$

(d) $H$ is an abelian group

If we take $G$ to be any abelian group clearly $Z(G)$ = $G$ so option (b) is false

Take G = $D_{18}$ the group is has only two elements in the centre so option (a) is false.

Since order of H = $4$ hence it must be abelian so (d) is correct.

But I am not so sure about option (c) Any hints will be helpful

This question has been asked here BEFORE [Let $G$ be a group of order $36$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with order 4. Then which is/are true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976376/let-g-be-a-group-of-order-36-and-h-be-a-subgroup-of-g-with-order-4-then).  But it didn't Answer my query so 
  I had to ask again.

Thank you

Comment: If (a) is false, then a fortiori (c) is also false

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in the question I actually meant to say $G$ instead of $Z(G)$

Comment: Strange, that same error was then also present in the 2014 question, even though you did not just copy paste from there ...

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976376/let-g-be-a-group-of-order-36-and-h-be-a-subgroup-of-g-with-order-4-then), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For third one, consider $G=S_3 \times S_3$ and $$H=\{(e,e),(e, (12)),((12),e),((12),(12))\}$$ Is $H$ normal in $G$?

Note that a subgroup is normal $\iff$ it is the Union of conjugacy classes of $G$

This result is very useful for symmetric groups, because conjugacy classes in these groups are easy to find by using cycle structure. So the question becomes

Is $H$ union of conjugacy classes of $G$?

Comment: No, because for a group to be normal we must have $xhx^{-1}$ $\in$  $H$ and for x= $((13),(13))$  h = $((12),e)$ this condition is violated.

Comment: Is my  reasoning correct ?

Comment: Yes correct! ..

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

$(\Bbb Z/3)^2$ has an automorphism $\phi\colon (a,b)\mapsto (-b,a)$ of order $4$. This allows us to construct a semidirect product $$(\Bbb Z/3)^2\rtimes_\phi\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z.$$
Note that $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is not normal here (namely, the right factor of a semidirect product is normal only if the action $\phi$ is trivial)

Answer (score 0):

For the third one we can also consider the sylow's theorem.
Here , 36 order group has sylow-2-subgroup.
So, $n_2=1+4k$ must divide the order of group, i.e. 36.

Then we will get $k=1$ and $k=2$ satisfies the criteria and so number of sylow-2-subgroup will be $n_2=1$ or $9$.
But if $H$ is normal in G then sylow-2-subgroup must be unique. Hence, $H$ is not normal in G.